# TikTok login kit: redirect not working after successful authentication

Tags: authentication, tiktok

I am working on integrating 'login with tiktok' on my website using [tiktok's login kit for web](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-web). I am able to connect to their oauth endpoint and after giving access from my tiktok account, I get redirected back to "https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/undefined" instead of the redirect url which I have specified in my app.

On inspecting the network calls, I see that there is a `404 not found` error from the call "https://open-api.tiktok.com/tiktok/v1/devportal/user?_t=1634687350899"

Has anyone else faced this? My earlier guess was that the tiktok account I am trying to sign in from is not found somehow. But I tried signing in with another tiktok account and got the same error.

Any guidance is much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For me, the reason was a slight mismatch between my Tiktok app's permission scopes to the requested ones (the ones you pass as query params in the GET request to https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/connect/). Once I aligned them it got resolved.

Comment: Super curious what you did as I have that url, but it's constantly giving me a redirect_uri error message. my redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/someAuthCallback.php. Do I need to attach anything to the end?